# passing data via prepareForSegue in Swift from UICollectionView to UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, segue

Output
**The Event ID is: Circle
Could not cast value of type 'ThisLondon.ViewController' (0x9c338) to 'UICollectionViewCell' (0x39dbd1a0).
(lldb)**

Yes "Circle" is being output, that is what I selected, great, although I can't get that to pass over the segue to the tableView?!

here is my code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "selectedTube" {
        let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! tubeDetailsTableViewController

        if let indexPath = collecView.indexPathForCell(sender as! UICollectionViewCell) {
            detailViewController.selectedTube = stationArray[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well since there is a cast taking place there (involving the two types mentioned), I would guess that `sender` is the view controller itself... You could try to put a breakpoint and inspect its value.

Comment: hmm, I'm sorry I don't understand, the first View is UICollectionView and the data I'm trying to pass to UITableView

Comment: Can you share a little information about _how_ the segue is actually triggered?

Comment: If I use this function, then thisTube will at first be equal to 'Circle' but then changes to nil
`func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("User tapped on: \(indexPath.row)")
        thisTube = stationArray[indexPath.row]
        NSLog("The Event ID is: \(thisTube)")
        performSegueWithIdentifier("selectedTube", sender: self)
    }`

Comment: I managed to do it, I wasn't getting form the UICollectionViewCell